# How to include / provide an entire codebase for mulitple subdomains

Tags: php

I have the following directoty structure on the server:

```
ROOT
 -> Subdomain 1
    -> File1.php
    -> ..
    -> File99.php
 -> Subdomain 2
    -> File1.php
    -> ..
    -> File99.php
 -> Subdomain 3
    -> File1.php
    -> ..
    -> File99.php
```

Every time I want to change the code, I have to change it in all subdomain folders.
I would therefore like to make the codebase available in a "Codebase" folder in order to reduce the maintenance effort.

```
ROOT
 -> Codebase
    -> File1.php
    -> ..
    -> File99.php
 -> Subdomain 1
 -> Subdomain 2
 -> Subdomain 3
```

My first thought / approach is to have the same file names in all subdomain folders and include the code from the codbase.

Subdomain 1
-> File1.php (require "./../Codebase/File1.php)

Is this practicable or are there more convenient solutions?

##### **UPDATE**

Maybe this is a possible solution:

```
ROOT
 -> Codebase
    -> index.php
    -> ..
    -> file99.php
 -> Subdomain 1
    -> login.php
    -> db_connection.php
    -> userdata.php
 -> Subdomain 2
    -> login.php
    -> db_connection.php
    -> userdata.php
 -> Subdomain 3, 4, n
```

The login script is executed on the subdomain and the path to the subdomain for database access, user data, ... is stored in a $Session variable.

The main website/codebase is executed in a shared folder. If a database connection is required, the login data is retrieved from the subdomain folder via the path stored in $Session.

Comment: Couple of thoughts. First, PHP has an include path for shared code specifically for this reason. Second, symlinks. Third, do they need dedicated folders in the first place?

Comment: Automated deployment scripts? I.e. CI/CD techniques.

Comment: Fourth, using `../../` to “break out” of the site’s root shouldn’t be a problem, as long as they stay isolated to that level only

Comment: Hi @ChrisHaas, thanks for your thoughts. I may have found a good solution that works well for my problem.

On the subdomain "company1.domain.com" I provide the login script and the user data, database connection, etc. and store the path to the subdomain in a $Session variable.

The shared code is located in a different folder and is executed there by each subdomain user. For the database connections, reading the user data, ... I retrieve the data from the subdomain folder via the path stored in the $Session.

What do you think? Are there any security concerns?

Comment: It really depends on how these subdomains interact with each other. For instance, if I have apple.example.com and evil-company.example.com, then sharing authentication between these is probably a bad idea. But if you have shoes.example.com and shirts.example.com, and these are just sub-brands of one giant happy company, then this might be okay. You should also make sure that nothing of value exists on the root domain, example.com, because of how cookie domain are used. If you _must_ have something on that, consider making it a subsite at www.example.com instead, with a redirect from root.

Comment: **Why there are multiple folders at all** in the first place? Why it isn't made just a single folder?

Comment: @YourCommonSense It's a webapp for driving schools. Each school has its own domain (cooldriver.drivingschool.com, smartdriver.drivingschool.com, etc.) Each school has its own database and so I think the best way is to put the login script, user data and DB connection in their own folder. To keep the maintenance effort for the codebase low, I would like to store the website in a shared folder.

Comment: There is not a single reason to have multiple folders. Only having a single folder will indeed keep the maintenance effort low. And exactly answers to your question